# Concatenate files with multiple words inside

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently new to Python and I would like to do the following:

In `text1.txt`, I will have:

```
1
2
7
9
```

In `text2.txt`, I will have:

```
1
2
2
2
3
4
```

I am looking for a solution that my output will look in this specific order:

```
1
2
7
9
2
2
3
4
```

Firstly, I would like to compare these 2 files and afterwards to get a concatenated file, but if one of the files has multiple times one word which it's common in both files, I would like that in the output, which should be also a file, to have it as many times as it is in the file that has the most of the same repeating wrong. In this case, `file2` has 3 times `2` and `file1` has 1 time `2`, so I would like to have it in the output 3 times `2`, but the number of extra times of `2` to be in the end. Also, what it is not common between 2 files should be added in the end of the output. 
I started like this and until now compares these 2 files and concatenates them, but I don't know how to add also the multiple common words found:

```
import glob
read_files=glob.glob("1.txt,output1.txt")
file1=open('1.txt','r')
file3=open('3.txt','r')
with open('3.txt', 'r') as file3:
    with open('1.txt', 'r') as file1:
        same1 = set(file3).difference(file1)

same1.discard('\n')

with open('output1.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same1:
        file_out.write(line)

filename=['output1.txt','1.txt']
with open('output_final.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filename:
           with open(fname) as infile:
                    for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

It is any possibility to choose 1 file from the filename list? Something like e.g. filename(1) to manipulate just 1st file or 2nd file? 
It is quite tricky to explain, but I think that the example can be used as a reference better than my explanation.

Comment: Make two dicts, save inside, then merge and take the max of each cell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you would ever need this kind of code, here it is:

```
import fileinput
import collections
import re
import csv
import xlrd

file1=open('1.txt','r')
file3=open('3.txt','r')
with open('3.txt', 'r') as file3:
    with open('1.txt', 'r') as file1:
        diff = set(file3).difference(file1)

diff.discard('\n')

with open('difference.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in diff:
        file_out.write(line)

finput = fileinput.FileInput('1.txt')
finput.next()
ginput = fileinput.FileInput('3.txt')
ginput.next()   

lines1=open('1.txt','r').read().splitlines()
lines2=open('3.txt','r').read().splitlines()

with open('duplicate.txt','w') as gout:
    count1 = collections.Counter(lines1)
    count2 = collections.Counter(lines2)

    final_lines = lines1
    seen = set()

    for line in lines2:
        if line not in seen:
            seen.add(line)
            if count1[line] < count2[line]:
                final_lines += ([line] * (count2[line] - count1[line]))

    for line in final_lines:
        gout.write("%s\n" % line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just load both the files as list (I am assuming that they are not huge) and then iterate over the first and remove those elements from the second and then concatenate the lists. Something like:

```
with open('text1.txt', 'r') as f:
    li1 = f.readlines()
with open('text2.txt', 'r') as f:
    li2 = f.readlines()

li1 = list(map(lambda t: int(t.strip()), li1))
li2 = list(map(lambda t: int(t.strip()), li2))

for i in li1:
    try:
        li2.remove(i)
    except ValueErorr:
        pass

li1.extend(li2)
```

`li1` should have the desired output now:

```
In [27]: print(li1)
[1, 2, 7, 9, 2, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: This will give union of set li1 and set li2 but OP wants something else

Comment: I have tried to apply this code to my code, but I get the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "out2.py", line 28, in <module>
    li1 = list(map(lambda t: int(t.strip()), li1))
  File "out2.py", line 28, in <lambda>
    li1 = list(map(lambda t: int(t.strip()), li1))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: I have figure out how to solve that error, but the output is not what I was expecting: [1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
Any other solution that would help?